# Chatterbot- multiple custom adapters don't work

Tags: python, django, chatterbot

I'm using the django integration.

settings.py

```
CHATTERBOT = {
    'name': 'chatbot0',
    'storage_adapter': "chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
    'logic_adapters': [
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
        #custom adapters
        'chatbot.adapters.adapter_1',
        'chatbot.adapters.adapter_2',

    ]
}
```

But adapter_2 doesnt work unless I remover adapter_1, and vise versa.
What is the problem?

Comment: how do you know they don't work? What do you have in these adapters? If they don't work then problem has to be in they code but you didn't show code. We can't read in your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the "confidence"; both adapters were working fine but the confidence of each was equal:

https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/index.html

> It is possible to enter any number of logic adapters for your bot to
> use. If multiple adapters are used, then the bot will return the
> response with the highest calculated confidence value. **If multiple
> adapters return the same confidence, then the adapter that is entered
> into the list first will take priority.**